# How to get information about ERROR from WSO2?

Tags: configuration, wso2

I am writing a logging system for WSO2. When I send GET request, I receive a information(time of request, method name etc), for this I made this config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="jms_in_flow" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="transactionId" expression="get-property('MessageID')"/>
    <clone continueParent="true">
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <property action="set" name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:api.ut.api_version" name="api_version" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:api.ut.version" name="api_short_version" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:api.ut.requestTime" name="api_request_time" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:REST_API_CONTEXT" name="api_context" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
                <call>
                    <endpoint>
                        <address uri="jms:/WSO2.Logi"/>
                    </endpoint>
                </call>
                <drop/>
            </sequence>
        </target>
    </clone>
</sequence>
```

From WSO2 I send logges to queue and it's work, but I don't know how error handling.
I try this:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="convert">
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
                <am:code>$1</am:code>
                <am:type>Status report</am:type>
                <am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
                <am:description>$2</am:description>
            </am:fault>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
    <header name="To" action="remove"/>
    <property name="HTTP_SC" value="555" scope="axis2"/>
    <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
    <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
    <property name="Authorization" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
    <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" scope="transport"/>
    <property name="Host" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
    <property name="Accept" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
    <property name="X-JWT-Assertion" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
    <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
    <send>
    <endpoint>
        <address uri="jms:/WSO2.Logi"/>
    </endpoint>
    </send>
</sequence>
```

where do I make a mistake?
documentation:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Error+Handling

UPD:
I applied Fault in sequence but this don't help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="fault_format" trace="disable">
  <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
      <Fault>
        <ERROR_CODE>$1</ERROR_CODE>
        <ERROR_MESSAGE>$2</ERROR_MESSAGE>
        <ERROR_DETAIL>$3</ERROR_DETAIL>
      </Fault>
    </format>
    <args>
      <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
      <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
      <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"/>
    </args>
  </payloadFactory>
  <send>
    <endpoint>
        <address uri="jms:/WSO2.LOG.TEST"/>
    </endpoint>
    </send>
</sequence>
```

Comment: jms_in_flow is a sequence which you can use to capture some information about the incoming requests. convert Sequence can be used to capture error flows via fault sequence and send a custom error message to the caller. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Please refer the below link which explains what in, out and fault sequences does. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Key+Concepts#KeyConcepts-Sequences

Comment: @Rans jms_in_flow is work, i send information about the incoming requests to queue, i don't know how to send information about fault to queue(sequence name="convert")

Comment: @Rans see UPD maybe you find mistake)

Comment: I'm missing some information here: what do you do to trigger the fault? Some faults (sadly) do not cause the faultsequence to be triggered. Also I do not see the onError="name" attribute in the sequence definition.

Comment: @Jan I want get information about authorization fault

Comment: So you pass forward the request, and there is a HTTP 401 unauthorized response? This is not a 'fault' but a valid response from the server. You need to <filter > on the HTTP_SC property to check the statuscode and then put the message in the error queue.

Comment: @Jan At the moment I get all the codes and do not filter them at all. I get all the codes 200-5 **. Fault is needed for handling errors of the form Invalid Credentials, the server returns this response, but I do not know how to configure the mediator to send this response to the queue

Comment: Yes, so take the following steps:
 - check response using filter mediator.
IF SUCCES: send to 'succes endpoint/queue'
ELSE:  send to 'failed' endpoint/queue